# Why do error occur with ternary operator in for cycle?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I have a question regarding ternary operator in Java.
I'm getting an error:

```
> Compilation error Main.java:14: error: unexpected type
>         (i%2==0) ? sum += i/2 : sum += i/2+1;
>                  ^ required: variable found:    value 1 error
```

I don't understand why?
Thank you!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] mas = {0,0,0};//new int[3];
    int sum=0;

    for (int i=0; i< mas.length; i++) {
        mas[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    for(int i : mas){
        (i%2==0) ? sum += i/2 : sum += i/2+1;
//            if(i%2 == 0) sum += i/2;
//            else sum += i/2+1;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```

Comment: try sum += (i%2 == 0) ? i/2 : (i/2)+1;

Comment: A simpler way to write this without conditions would be `sum+= i/2 + i%2`

Comment: correct expression write by @Stultuske

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring it in the incorrect way:

`sum += (i%2==0) ? i/2 : i/2+1;`

The order is: variable, assignation operator, condition, question mark, value if condition is fulfilled, value otherwise.

Comment: i/2+1 = i/(2+1)

Answer (score 2):

It does not work like that. The Ternary Operator needs Expressions. The definition looks like this

> ConditionalExpression:
>      ConditionalOrExpression
>      ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : ConditionalExpression

You instead have two statements. You either use the normal `if-else` for that or change it to an assignment like this

```
sum += i%2 == 0 ? i/2 : i/2+1;
```

Comment: Not _entirely_ correct, because `sum += i/2` is in fact an expression. But the _entire_ ternary operator construct is itself an expression and can only be in a context requiring an expression, not a statement. E.g. `int dummy = (i%2==0) ? sum += i/2 : (sum += i/2+1);` compiles ok.

Comment: Yes! Thanks.Actually sum = (i%2==0) ? sum+i/2 : sum+i/2+1; works.